# preventing string concatenation in javascript function during JSP compilation

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
var result = null;

function setSendButton(userInput){
   var clicked=userInput;
   result = "<%=mb.myMethod(clicked)%>";
}
```

where `myMethod` is a java method called through using jsp tags. it is defined as:

```
public boolean myMethod(String isClicked){
  if(isClicked.equals("true")){
     return true;
  }else{
     return false;
  }
}
```

for some reason stepping i got a JSP compilation error that compiles the code where `var clicked` value of "true" is not passed and `clicked` becomes a string during JSP compilation like so: `mb.myMethod(clicked)` instead of `mb.myMethod("true")`

Comment: The method myMethod(String) in the type mb is not applicable for the arguments...what type exactly is passed through for `var isClicked`...is it automatically a string?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass a parameter (at client runtime) to a function that processes on the server.

Comment: please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534079/referenceerror-for-javascript-function-involving-server-side-callbacks-in-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't work like that.
The Java code in JSP is translated and compiled on the server side before sending to the client's browser. The javascript variable is available only after the JSP is translated and compiled to become a HTML file and sent to the client browser. At that time, The `mb.myMethod` is already already executed on the server side.

In short, you can passed java code to js assignment but not the other way around.

Comment: This answer.  The only way to do this is to ask the Javascript to call a server-side page (AJAX).

Comment: hi @SandyGifford can you help? i have a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534079/referenceerror-for-javascript-function-involving-server-side-callbacks-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
var result = null;

function setSendButton(){
   result = "<%=mb.myMethod(true)%>";
}
```

Comment: yes it would but lets say i have myMethod(String input) and i want to pass that through `"<%=mb.myMethod(input)%>"` how will that work?

Comment: I see, I think this is what you're looking for: `result = "<%=mb.myMethod(" + clicked + ")%>";`

Comment: no that doesnt work, it doesnt give you the value of true like `mb.myMethod(true)` but actually concatenates it as `mb.myMethod(+ clicked +)`

Comment: hi @thewebguy can you help? i have a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534079/referenceerror-for-javascript-function-involving-server-side-callbacks-in-jsp